# ERROR: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value in save mode

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the company model and company table. The name is a column in the companies table. I have a form, and after I submit the form, all the data is sent ( I tried to debug) but is not stored in `Company` when I use `$company->save()`.

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'slug' => 'required|unique:companies,slug',
        'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }
    
    $companyData = $request->all();
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $imageName = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        // Store the image in the storage/app/public/posts directory
        $image->storeAs('public/companies', $imageName);
        $companyData['image'] = 'companies/'.$imageName;
    }

    $company = new Company();
    $company->name = $request->input('name');
    $company->slug = $request->input('slug');
    $company->image = $companyData['image'];
    $company->status = $request->has('status');
    $company->name = 'Hardcoded Value';
    $company->save();
}
```

**Model**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Astrotomic\Translatable\Contracts\Translatable as TranslatableContract;
use Astrotomic\Translatable\Translatable;
use function PHPSTORM_META\map;

class Company extends Model implements TranslatableContract
{
    use HasFactory;
    use Translatable;
    // public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = [];
    public $table='companies';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'slug',
        'image',
        'status',
    ];

    protected $translatedAttributes = ['name'];
}
```

I tried to debug, but in `dd($request->all())`, I see the 'name', but in `dd($company)`, I don`t see any 'name.'

Comment: Not 100% sure how the translatable library works but if it stores translations on a related table **only** and you have an actual `name` column in your main table, then you will need to drop that one as it will not be filled.

Comment: Do you mean that I can`t fill the 'name' in the 'companies' table, if I will be using translations?

Comment: I mean that you have assigned the responsibility to deal with the `name` to the translatable package and you will need to ensure that your database table is designed to reflect that. As I said I am not 100% sure how the library works but from a quick look it seems to store all translations (incl. the default one) in a related table.

Comment: Check [their test cases](https://github.com/Astrotomic/laravel-translatable/blob/main/tests/TestCase.php) they seem to only define the translated attributes in the `<model>_translations` table only so I think you need to also do the same

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

$company = new Company();
$request->validate([
    'name' => 'required|max:255',
    'slug' => 'required|unique:companies,slug',
    'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048',
]);

$companyData = $request->all();
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $imageName = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

    // Store the image in the storage/app/public/posts directory
    $image->storeAs('public/companies', $imageName);
    $companyData['image'] = 'companies/'.$imageName;
}

   $company->name = $request->input('name');
   $company->slug = $request->input('slug');
   $company->image = $companyData['image'];
   $company->status = $request->has('status');
   $company->name = 'Hardcoded Value';
   $company->save();
}
```